# How do I make a div disappear when clicking away?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am trying to make my form div disappear when I click away from it. The function for this action was working fine until I also added another div to create an overlay of subtle opacity underneath the form after clicking on the add book button to make it appear. Is there a way to have both events happening without causing one of them to no longer work?

Thank you in advance.

HTML

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/jmq2vxa.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/open-book.png"/>
    <title>My Library</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="head-box">
    <h1>My Library</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="body-box">
    <button id="addBook">Add Book</button>
  </div>

  <!-----Form information----->
  <div class="form-popup">
    <div class="form-content"
    <form action="example.com/path" class="form-container" id="popUpForm">
      <h3>add new book</h3>
      <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title">
      <input type="author" id="author" placeholder="Author">
      <input type="pages" id="pages" placeholder="Pages">
    <div class="isRead">
      <label for="readOption">Have you read it?</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="readOption" name="readOption">
    </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="invisibleDiv"></div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    * {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


h1 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 8vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

.head-box {
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20vh;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e0f3ff;
}

h2 {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 5vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

h3 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 4vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

button {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 20vh;
  font-size: 3vh;
  background-color: #27476E;
  border-radius: 22px;
  border-style: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  color:#ffffff;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #192c44;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg,#d0edff,#9DD1F1) no-repeat;
}

.body-box {
  margin: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* The pop up form - hidden by default */

.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9;
}

.form-content {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 35vh; 
  height: 45vh;
  border: 3px solid #001D4A;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 17px;
  gap: 10px;
}


.isRead{
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

input {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d0edff;
  border: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#submit {
  margin: 4px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#invisibleDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

JS

```
const popUpForm = document.querySelector(".form-popup");
const button = document.querySelector("#addBook");
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');


document.getElementById('invisibleDiv').onclick = function()
{
   popUpForm.style.display = "none"; 
   overlay.style.display = "none";
};


button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popUpForm.style.display = "block";
  overlay.style.display = "block";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because the `overlay` is place on top of the `invisibleDiv`. So you click event on the `invisibleDiv` is not triggering.

When you add css position other then static, they will have this stacking context apply to them, refer to the link below
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

You can just add the click event on the `overlay`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and for the link! When I changed both positions to fixed in css it started to work! I wonder why..

Comment: to make it easy to understand, when you apply position: absolute/relative/fixed , it will make it closer to the screen compare to normal element. So it will has the possibility to place above other element. It is like increased z axis of the element. You can control it with the z-index in css

Comment: Ah interesting, I did not know that! Thank you for your help.